# Showing response time in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rack

I want to display a `This page took x seconds` widget at the bottom of every page in my rails application.  I would like `x` to reflect the approximate amount of time the request spent on my server.  What is a good way of doing this?

Edit: My production server is on phusion passenger and development environment on mongerel. Would love to have a solution that works well with both.

Update: I think for the purpose of this question, the railscast solution is a bit overboard.  I modified the middleware suggested in there to just set up a constant and used that in my layout.  This way I won't have to change any content-length headers.  Thanks again neutrino.  Rack middleware are very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I thought, that's a good use for a rack middleware. Then I thought uh, Ryan has got one on this. Then voila, a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) on how to measure the response time via rack middleware :)

Obviously works with both mongrel and passenger.